# How to maintain position of column data by adding blank for empty data when converting to list?

Tags: python, list

I have data in which each row has some amount of data in up to 6 columns but not in all the columns. Sometimes the the data is in columns 3 and 4, sometimes 4 and 6, etc. I want to create a list out of each row (and extend the list to continue adding rows) and add a blank item in the list if there is no data in a column. Essentially maintaining that each row has 6 pieces of data, even if some are blank. The spacing between columns is not regular, or at least cannot be guaranteed to be regular.

When each row has 6 pieces of data I have no issue since I can just join, split, and append to build my list. The issue is with rows with fewer than 6 items.

See below for example data.

```
CCW40109           D+L             -0.13                         0.60
CCW40109           4D+L+OBE                        8.77         17.38
CCW40109           4D+L-OBE        -8.56                       -17.65
CCW40109           4D+L+SSE                                     24.22          12.04
```

Here is how I want the list to look after running through every row. A single list of 24 elements with blank elements for the blank columns.

```
[CCW40109,D+L,-0.13, ,0.60, ,CCW40109,4D+L+OBE, ,8.77,17.38, ,CCW40109,4D+L-OBE,-8.56, ,-17.65, ,CCW40109,4D+L+SSE, , ,24.22,12.04]
```

I've been banging my head on the wall on this one. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't use split for this.  You will have to have a list of the column positions.  For each column, take `line[start:end].strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like this:

```
#123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-
data = """\
CCW40109           D+L             -0.13                         0.60
CCW40109           4D+L+OBE                        8.77         17.38
CCW40109           4D+L-OBE        -8.56                       -17.65
CCW40109           4D+L+SSE                                     24.22          12.04"""

cols = [0, 19, 36, 50, 64, 79, 999]

alldata = []
for line in data.splitlines():
    fields = [ line[c1:c2-1].rstrip() for c1,c2 in zip(cols,cols[1:]) ]
    alldata.append( fields )

from pprint import pprint
pprint(alldata)
```

Output:

```
[['CCW40109', 'D+L', '0.13', '', ' 0.60', ''],
 ['CCW40109', '4D+L+OBE', '', ' 8.77', '17.38', ''],
 ['CCW40109', '4D+L-OBE', '8.56', '', '17.65', ''],
 ['CCW40109', '4D+L+SSE', '', '', '24.22', '12.04']]
```